# The iso name of Windows 10 anniversary update

Tags: windows-10

I'm now downloading an ISO of windows 10 from my faculty dreamspark named

```
en_windows_10_multiple_editions_version_1607_updated_jul_2016_x64_dvd_9058187.iso
```

I want to make sure if it is the anniversary update of windows 10 before formatting my hard disk

Any information from the ISO file name?

Comment: 1607 is the anniversary release. You need to check your current version: 32/64-bit, home basic/premium/pro/enterprise/education, single/multi-language/international. It's easy to get it wrong - it took me three installations to find the right ISO to match my licence. If it's a new licence, choose what you want to pay for.

Comment: The update your asking about was released on Aug 2nd 2016.  The version is 1607.  That is the only ISO from dreamspark that would be Version 1607.  It is indeed 1607.

Comment: @AFH I am x64, it's OK about this, but what about the type? I think I will choose them during installation and my serial does not specify certain type.

Comment: @Ramhound But the iso name contains jul2016 not aug2016, this is what makes me confused

Comment: <sigh> 1607 = July 2016;  It was released on August 2nd.  It still is the more recent ISO

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Anniversary Update is [version 1607](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history), which is what you have listed.